# Embed rtmp on web page with pageUrl parameter

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, flowplayer

I can embed `rtmp` urls on web pages using players like `jwplayer, flowplayer..` if `rtmp` url does not need any extra parameters like `pageUrl`. How can I embed and make it work if I need parameters like these, how can I pass this values on web page?

Comment: RTMP does not need that parameter - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming

Comment: Some streams are protected and they need this parameters to be dumped. We can dump live streams using `rtmpdump`. Some live streams can not be dumped only with rtmp url, they need extra parameters. `e.g. rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://host/playpath/file  --pageUrl abc.com --swfUrl abc.swf` Without these parameters connection is rejected, hence it does not play on web pages, as well. I need to pass page url parameter.

Comment: Do you mean like a secure token?

Comment: No, I will give an example, `trt1`  is a tv channel in Turkey and its rtmp address `rtmp://mn-l.mncdn.com/trt1/trt13` . If you have `rtmpdump` installed try to dump it with command `rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://mn-l.mncdn.com/trt1/trt13`, then it will be rejected you can not play this stream anywhere, because it needs one more parameter which is `swfUrl`, then you can dump and do any job on this stream with `rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://mn-l.mncdn.com/trt1/trt13 --swfVfy http://mnhst.mncdn.net/players/player/flowplayer.unlimited-3.2.16.swf`. Some needs `pageUrl` where live stream is broadcasted.

Comment: Do you have a sample stream?

Comment: `rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://188.0.226.103/tv/bt1h28qn  -p http://www.castok.com | ffplay -i pipe:0`  Now live stream only has sound not video, you can check it from here [bt sports 1](http://www.castok.com/channel.php?live=bt1)

Comment: This works fine and is using JW Player 6 here. Is this your site?

Comment: No, not mine, it is just a sample, can you copy paste javascript code here?

Comment: I include this `<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/BzKCBJzhEeOssyIACi0I_Q.js"></script>` library is not it jw 6 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48338/discussion-between-mustafa-yavuz-and-ethan-jwplayer)

Comment: Sorry, what is your question here?

Comment: It gives net connection error for `rtmp://188.0.226.103/tv/bt1h28qn` which needs pageUrl parameter also. In jwplayer documentation I can not see any way to pass this parameter.  `<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "rtmp://188.0.226.103/tv/bt1h28qn",
    });
</script>` Is there anything like `pageUrl: "http://www.castok.com"`

Comment: We do not support that parameter.